# Inverse of an absolute value

Tags: inverse, absolute-value, inverse-function

Suppose $f(x) = e^{-|x|}$ then it follows:

$$y = e^{-|x|} $$

$$x = e^{-|y|} $$

$$ \log(x) = -|y| $$

$$-\log(x) = |y| $$

Im assuming the equation for the inverse depends on the range of $x$, and the range of $x$ is $0$ to $\infty$. I am just not sure where to go next.

Answer (score 1):

In your second step

$$y = e^{-|x|} \iff x = e^{-|y|} $$

you should specify you are changing variables to avoid confusion.

To find the inverse note that $f:\mathbb R \to (0,1]$  is even and that $f(x)$ is monotonic for $x\ge 0$ then we can find the inverse for the restriction

$$f:[0,\infty) \to (0,1] $$

that is

$$y = e^{-x} \iff \log y =\log (e^{-x})=-x$$

then the inverse function is

$$f(x)=-\log x$$

In a similar way for the restriction

$$f:(-\infty,0] \to (0,1] $$

the inverse function is

$$f(x)=\log x$$

Comment: Sorry, I am a little confused, I am trying to find the inverse so why shouldn't I switch the x and y?

Comment: @KevinG Ah ok sorry, you should specify the change of variables otherwise it is really confusing what you are looking for. In general it is better obtain $x$ as a function of y and then switch the variables. In any case to find the inverse we need restrict the original function. I revise that.